# Eigenvector and eigenvalue for power of matrix, will eigenvectors remain the same?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that if you raise a matrix $ A $ to let's say a power of 5, assuming that $ A$ is a 3 x 3 matrix and has 3 distinct eigenvalues, each of the eigenvalues will also be raised to the power of 5.

My question is, will the eigenvectors of the new $A^5$ still remain the same as A?

Comment: Yes, if $Av=\lambda v$, then $A^5v=\lambda^5 v$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ah, thank you

Comment: If all of the eigenvalues are fifth roots of 1, then $A^5$ might be $I$, with extra eigenvectors

Comment: @Empy2, so are you saying that there may be a possibility that the eigenvector will not be the same as the original?

Comment: Yes.  For example rotation of $2\pi/5$ about the $z$ axis, then $A^5$ is rotation of $2\pi$ so $A^5=I$.  As J.W.Tanner says, it eill include all the old ones but there may be new ones as well.

Comment: @Empy2 % A^5 %may be different, but does it mean there will be new eigenvectors? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Every vector is an eigenvector of $I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Say $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $A$; i.e., $A\vec v=\lambda \vec v$.

Then $A^5\vec v=A^4 A\vec v=A^4 \lambda \vec v=\lambda A^4 \vec v=\lambda A^3 A\vec v=\lambda A^3 \lambda\vec v=\lambda^2 A^3\vec v$

$=\lambda^2A^2A\vec v=\lambda^2A^2\lambda\vec v=\lambda^3A^2\vec v=\lambda^3 A A\vec v=\lambda^3A \lambda\vec v=\lambda^4A\vec v=\lambda^5\vec v.$

So $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $A^5$ with eigenvalue $\lambda^5$.